# Установка Nuxt с помощью docker-compose?

Tags: nuxt.js

Подскажите как правильно установить Nuxt с помощью docker-compose?

docker-compose.yml:

```
 version: "3"
    services:
       nuxt-app:
         build:
           context: .
           dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www/nuxt
    networks:
      - nuxt-network
    networks:
      nuxt-network:
      driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.16.3-alpine3.9
WORKDIR /var/www/nuxt
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install && npm run start
RUN npm run dev
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: не получается установить nuxt c помощью docker-compose npm вроде установился не запускается команда nuxt start и не запускается сам контейнер